# Is it possible to represent Entity's field Map<Enum, Entity> in JPA with just 2 tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Given:

```
    enum Language
    {
        EN
        DE
        IT
        FR
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "translation")
    class Translation
    {
        Long entry_id; // mapped to Entry
        Language language; // creates primary key with entry_id
        String content;

        // more fields ...
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "entry")
    class Entry
    {
        Long id;
        Map<Language, Translation> translations;

        // more fields ...
    }
```

1. Does JPA 3.1 and Hibernate 6.1.5+ allow to represent above in relational database (MySQL) with just 2 tables, such as:

```
    table entry (id, stuff)
    table translation (entry_id, language, content) primary key [entry_id, language]
```

2. Also consider extension to above problem, where content is another @ManyToOne relation:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "translation")
    class Translation
    {
        Long entry_id; // mapped to Entry
        Language language; // creates primary key with entry_id
        List<Post> posts;
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "post")
    class Post
    {
        Long id;
        String content;
    }
```

How would one approach this in order to have most of all worlds:

- Map<Language, Translation> on Java side
- Least amount of tables on DB side, to not do pointless joins
- Optimal read/writes (ideally lazy), so that values of the Map<Language, Translation> are not read from DB unless necessary (only Keys are known), and are especially not written every time just one entry changes (that's why we have keys, don't we?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
enum Language
{
    EN
    DE
    IT
    FR
}

@Embeddable
class Translation
{
    String content;

    // more fields ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "entry")
class Entry
{
    Long id;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "translation")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "language")
    Map<Language, Translation> translations;

    // more fields ...
}
```

Comment: Great solution to the first part of the question. This pointed me towards topics that include Embeddable in ElementCollection. Apparently it is a common question if the Embeddable values can hold relations to other Entities, and as of now it is not allowed, which is even signaled by a very descriptive exceptions by Hibernate itself when attempted. This commend effectively answers rest of the question. I'd also like to note that ElementCollection is always loaded and saved with parent entity, which might not be optimal with large data.